# Angular5: select [selected] not work for the first time

Tags: angular

The value is not selected on the first time the page load in Angular 5 app even tough both value and ngModel values using the same property id.

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="states.length > 1">  
    <select [(ngModel)]="trip?.state.id" #state="ngModel" name="stateId" id="stateId" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">                                       
        <option [ngValue]="null">{{defaultSelect}}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let s of states" [ngValue]="s.state.id">{{s.state.name}}</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

The expected result is a selected state value shown inside the select component.
The actual result is the select component with empty value.

Comment: you should reproduce your issue in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Are you sure the selected `state.id` exists in the `<option>`s?

Comment: remove the "safe" operator in ngModel, you can use `<select *ngIf="trip"`..>` or split [(ngModel)] in `[ngModel]="trip? trip.state.id:null (ngModelChange)="trip.state.id=$event"`

Comment: Can you put what states object and trip object looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes with `[(ngModel)]="trip?.state.id"` that is changing directly your state.id, not selecting another object from your states.

Without knowing very well what your real code looks like I would say that the best way to go it's to use a `stateSelected` variable with the id that you can use later.

**You can see the live exmaple here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-selectngmodel-55583749?file=src/app/selector/selector.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing two things:
change id to a real object:

```
<option *ngFor="let s of states" [ngValue]="s.state.id">{{s.state.name}}</option>
```

to

```
<option *ngFor="let s of states" [ngValue]="s.state">{{s.state.name}}</option>
```

Also I made use of comparison mechanism, here is part of the select tag:

```
[compareWith]="compareStatesByOptionId"
```

And the method from the component is:

```
compareStatesByOptionId(idFirst, idSecond) {        
    return idFirst && idSecond && idFirst.id == idSecond.id;         
  }
```

I hope it help someone who facing this problem.